# C# Finishing Background worker with custom error

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, backgroundworker

I have a Background worker (NET 3.5 & Visual Studio 2008) that does some long time task:

```
        private void BWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = GetFileName();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                // Do long task
            }
            else
            {
               // Finish background worker with a custom error message
               // in order to receive it in BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted and log it. Some kind of:
                 e.Error.Message = "my custom message error".
            }
        }

        private void BWorker_ProcessChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Logger.Process("Cancelled.");
            }
            else if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Logger.Process("Successfully completed");
            }
            else
            {
                // Log here my custom error
                Logger.Error(string.Format("Completed with errors: {0}", e.Error.Message));
            }
        }
```

During long task I check many things, so if one fails I want to "force" background worker to finish with a custom error depending on the situation (If anything fails no need to continue executing background worker). This error then will be printed to a log in BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to terminate your process right away you can `throw` an exception at exactly that point. Make sure that the exception is not caught on the way upwards the calling hierarchy. This will terminate the current running process and `BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` will be called. Then you will end up in your `else` clause where you can log the message.

```
throw new Exception("My custom Message");
```

Applied to your simple example it would look like the following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
{
    // Do long task
}
else
{
     // Finish background worker with a custom error message
     // in order to receive it in BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted and log it. 
     throw new Exception("my custom message error");.
}
```

You can also create your own custom exception and throw it. How to do it is explained in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `DoWork` method runs on a seperate background/worker thread,  exceptions are handled differently. When an exception is thrown, they should be handled in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Like this example:

```
private void BWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string filename = GetFileName();

    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( filename ) )
    {
        // Do long task
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "my custom message error" );
    }
}

private void BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender , RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.Error != null )
    {
        // my custom message error
        Logger.Process( e.Error.ToString() );
    }
    else if ( e.Cancelled )
    {
        Logger.Process( "Cancelled." );
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Process( "Success." );
    }
}
```

It is best practice to throw the type exception that is more clear then the unspecific `Exception`. It simply doesnt contain any usefull information. And you have to use a catch block that catches all exceptions.

I generally use the `InvalidOperationException` alot. You don't need to create a custom exception. Use the one that are in the .NET Framework unless you need to log specific information for a type. Or if want someone to handle something explicitly.